# change the default skin for applications in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, look-and-feel, skin

I'm developing a Java application using `Netbeans`, and I want to change the default skin for the `JFrame` and buttons ...

I googled about it and I couldn't find anything.

In Visual Studio I was using `SkinCrafter`.

Is there any program or addon that allows me to change the default skin for applications in `Netbeans` ?

Comment: Try [Java gui look and feel changes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1165780/2040040) to learn L&F and [Java Look and Feel (L&F)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3954616/2040040) to get a lot of possibilities for L&Fs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try {
        // Set System L&F
    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    // or UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
    // or UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.motif.MotifLookAndFeel")
} 
catch (Exception e) {
   // handle exception
}
```

[Oracle site about](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

for installed skins:

```
    for( LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels() ) {
        System.out.println( info.getName() );
    }
```

Comment: where I can find those skins ?

Comment: These skins are built-in for jre. You dont have to download.